# Can anyone make my Chinese-English translation sound better?

Tags: translation

I need to translate this passage in traditional Chinese into English:

**教學年資：在本校升等時職級滿三年為50分，每增授課一學期加1分，最高分為70分。**

Here is my own translation (Please bear in mind that I am still learning to how to translate):

*Years of teaching: To apply for promotion, the teaching staff needs to have fulfilled 3 years of service to obtain 50 credits with one additional credit for every course taught over 1 semester. The maximum of credits shall not exceed 70.*

Any thoughts?

Comment: "在本校升等時" somehow this doesn't make sense to me, thou I can see what it could possible means in your translation.

Comment: @Alex 升=up, 等=等級=level, so literally it says "level up". Anyhow HK expressions in Chinese usually sound odd even to mainlanders' ears.

Comment: Years of teaching: To apply for promotion, the teaching staff  must have fulfilled 3 years of service credited for 50 points, with one additional point for every course taught over 1 semester, ceilinged by 70.

Comment: @Stan it would be 在本校升'級'時 if it's HK expression, that's why I am wondering

Comment: Anyhow, how about:  

Teaching Seniority: For promotion, 50 points of credit will be given to any staff fulfilled 3 years of teaching services, with 1 point of credit in addition to each course taught throughout the semester.  The maximum points of credit will not goes above 70

Comment: @Alex 「在本校升級時職級⋯」it seems the original text just aims for eliminating the repetition of the character 級.

Comment: @Stan I see what you mean there, however I don't believe "升等" is a common phase, as far as a local HK concerned.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the focus of this question is on improving an English translation. Without further clarification from the OP, this reads a bit too much like a question about _English_ style/grammar, which isn't appropriate for this site.

Comment: It is Taiwanese Mandarin, or Mandarin that is used in Taiwan.

Comment: Found in http://ope.nsysu.edu.tw/ezfiles/17/1017/img/1222/477277431.pdf

Answer (score 1):

在本校升等時，職級滿三年為50分，每增授課一學期加1分，最高分為70分
When applying for promotion at the University, those who have held their current rank for three years will receive 50 points, with an additional point for each semester of teaching beyond [the three years], up to a maximum of 70 points.

The word 申請 'apply for' is omitted at the beginning (在本校申請升等時) and there should be a comma after that. The word 'rank' 職級 is used oddly, I think 以原職級任教滿三年 or 服務滿三年 would make more sense. The intent is probably that one must hold each rank for a minimum of 3 years before applying for promotion (assistant to associate, associate to full), but this wording doesn't really make that clear. 每增 is also not very smooth.

The main problem with the translation is that 'credit' is not right here, this is a point system; also for every course taught over 1 semester is not right, the intent of the Chinese text is clearly to count semesters of teaching, not courses taught